# FutureTask in android

Tags: java, android, futuretask

I'm very new to Android so maybe my question is a bit of a beginner. I want to use the futureTask method in my program, but I really do not know how to use it. I have a sample code of this method and I want to combine it with my own code. `onActivityResult()` is my code that I want to process in the background. I tried to embed the code in the sample code instead of `call()` but got an error

this is `sample code`:

```
private static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
 
public static Future<String> startComputation() throws IOException {
    return pool.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
            return "finish computation";
        }
    });
}
 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    final Future<String> contentsFuture = startComputation();
     
    while (!contentsFuture.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("computation in progress...");
        System.out.println("do another work");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    }
     
    System.out.println(contentsFuture.get());
     
    System.exit(0);
}
```

and my `MainAvtivity` code:

```
package com.example.imen_yar;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.chaquo.python.PyException;
import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton b_main;
    Button b_link;
    TextView text;
    
    String interpreterOutput = "";
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @SuppressLint({"UseCompatLoadingForDrawables", "SetTextI18n"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b_main = findViewById(R.id.b_main);
        b_link = findViewById(R.id.b_link);
        text = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        b_link.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
        NavigationView nvDrawer = findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
        // To run Python Interpreter
        if(!Python.isStarted()){
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
        }
        b_main.setOnClickListener(view ->{
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        });
    }



    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Context context = this;

            String path = RealPathUtil.getRealPath(context,uri);

            if(path != null){
                Python py = Python.getInstance();

                String code = "import vt\n";
                code += "import hashlib\n";
                code += "import time\n";

                code += "client = vt.Client(\"e9481497c3198559e299e966ec79be2ece56bf903cd0308474f8e3059aad6ee5\")\n";

                code += "def check():\n";
                code += "    try:\n";
                code += "        with open(r\"" + path + "\",\"rb\") as f:\n";
                code += "            bytes = f.read() # read the entire file as bytes\n";
                code += "            readable_hash = hashlib.sha256(bytes).hexdigest()\n";
                code += "        file = client.get_object(\"/files/\" + readable_hash)\n";
                code += "        x = str(file.last_analysis_stats)\n";
                code += "        n = 109\n";
                code += "        if x[n] + x[n+1] + x[n+2] + x[n+3] + x[n+4] + x[n+5] + x[n+6] + x[n+7] + x[n+8] == \"malicious\":\n";
                code += "            t = x[n + 12]\n";
                code += "        elif x[n+1] + x[n+2] + x[n+3] + x[n+4] + x[n+5] + x[n+6] + x[n+7] + x[n+8] + x[n+9] == \"malicious\":\n";
                code += "            t = x[n + 13]\n";
                code += "        elif x[n+2] + x[n+3] + x[n+4] + x[n+5] + x[n+6] + x[n+7] + x[n+8] + x[n+9] + x[n+10] == \"malicious\":\n";
                code += "            t = x[n + 14]\n";
                code += "        elif x[n+3] + x[n+4] + x[n+5] + x[n+6] + x[n+7] + x[n+8] + x[n+9] + x[n+10] + x[n+11] == \"malicious\":\n";
                code += "            t = x[n + 15]\n";
                code += "        elif x[n+4] + x[n+5] + x[n+6] + x[n+7] + x[n+8] + x[n+9] + x[n+10] + x[n+11] + x[n+12] == \"malicious\":\n";
                code += "            t = x[n + 16]\n";
                code += "        elif x[n+5] + x[n+6] + x[n+7] + x[n+8] + x[n+9] + x[n+10] + x[n+11] + x[n+12] + x[n+13] == \"malicious\":\n";
                code += "            t = x[n + 17]\n";
                code += "        elif x[n+6] + x[n+7] + x[n+8] + x[n+9] + x[n+10] + x[n+11] + x[n+12] + x[n+13] + x[n+14] == \"malicious\":\n";
                code += "            t = x[n + 18]\n";
                code += "        if t == \"0\":\n";
                code += "            print(\"file is safe\")\n";
                code += "        else:\n";
                code += "            print(\"file isn't safe\")\n";
                code += "    except:\n";
                code += "        #print(\"oh. it's a new file!!\")\n";
                code += "        check2()\n";

                code += "def check2(): \n";
                code += "    with open(r\"" + path + "\", \"rb\") as f:\n";
                code += "        analysis = client.scan_file(f, wait_for_completion=True)\n";
                code += "    while True:\n";
                code += "        print(\"checking\")\n";
                code += "        analysis = client.get_object(\"/analyses/{}\", analysis.id)\n";
                code += "        #print(analysis.status)\n";
                code += "        if analysis.status == \"completed\":\n";
                code += "            check()\n";
                code += "            break\n";
                code += "        time.sleep(10)\n";

                code += "check()\n";

                PyObject sys = py.getModule("sys");
                PyObject io = py.getModule("io");
                PyObject console = py.getModule("interpreter");
                PyObject textOutputStream = io.callAttr("StringIO");

                sys.put("stdout", textOutputStream);

                try {
                    console.callAttrThrows("mainTextCode", code);
                    interpreterOutput = String.valueOf(textOutputStream.callAttr("getvalue"));
                }catch (PyException e){
                    interpreterOutput = e.getMessage();
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }

                String output_one = "safe\n";
                output_one += "Unclosed client session\n";
                output_one += "client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000252B05A5F40>\n";
                output_one += "Unclosed connector\n";
                output_one += "connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x00000252B05D3640>, 243493.796)]']\n";
                output_one += "connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000252ADC3CA90>";

                String output_two = "isn't safe\n";
                output_two += "Unclosed client session\n";
                output_two += "client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000252B05A5F40>\n";
                output_two += "Unclosed connector\n";
                output_two += "connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x00000252B05D3640>, 243493.796)]']\n";
                output_two += "connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000252ADC3CA90>";

                if (interpreterOutput != null) {
                    if(interpreterOutput.equals(output_one)){
                        System.out.println("file is safe");
                        text.setText("safe");
                    }else if(interpreterOutput.equals(output_two)){
                        System.out.println("file isn't safe!");
                        text.setText("isn't safe!");
                    }

                }
                ///System.out.println(interpreterOutput);
                //text.setText("not run");
            }
        }
    }
}
//salam
```

can you help me?